# Full-width image on the page with Orbit plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, width, orbit

I have to do a slider that is full-width page... I attach an image because I think that it is easier than explain it:

[image]

I have the body/page that is 100% width; then, I have a div "content" where I develop my website that is 980px; And in the end, I would like to have an header, the slider, that is full-width page..

The problem is that when i resize the page, the images of the slider are resized too, both width and height... Id like to have the fixed size of the iamge and an overflow hidden.

Following my css:

```
.orbit-container { height:220px !important; overflow: hidden; /*width: 100%;*/ position: relative; background: none; margin: 5px auto; }
.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container img { width:100%; }
.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > *:first-child { margin-left: 0%; }
.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > * { position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; margin-left: 100%; }
```

And here my HTML :

```
<div id="page">
    <header>
        <ul id="slider" data-orbit>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/../Styles/img/slider/privati/toystory.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
        <div class="line-separator_orange"></div>
    </header>
    ...
</div>
```

page and header don't have any particular css.

Can anyone help me please? Thank you

Comment: would be helpful to see the html.. http://fiddle.net it up ;] on first look though, it seems you just need to give either your image or their container a FIXED width, if you want them not to resize..

Comment: Ok... I edited the original post... I'm not sure I should give a fixed width... without orbit I can put a simple full-width image as header... and if I resize the window, the image remain the same... just the "overflow is hidden"..